# php numeric value to html array

Tags: php, html

I have a numeric value from an array

```
<p><b>Rating</b>: <?= $arr->rating; ?></p>
```

which outputs in browser source code

```
<p><b>Rating</b>: 5.100000</p>
```

(This is a rating of 5.100000 out of 10.)

How would I go about displaying the rating numeric value as an array of five stars?

For example, the 5.100000 values would be displayed as two and 1/2 stars out of five like this.

```
<li>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half"></i>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star empty"></i>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star empty"></i>
</li>
```

Comment: html... array...? That's not a thing. Your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: can you give us an example of what you need as final result?

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that you want to automatically generate the required number of stars (and half stars) based on a number.

Comment: if say the $arr->rating value is "5.100000"
I would like my output to be

            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star empty"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star empty"></i>

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is ceiling function like the following: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php#85430

Comment: how can 5.1 result in 2.5 stars?

Comment: "how can 5.1 result in 2.5 stars"
5.1 out of 10 rounds to 5.  
the conversion is 1/2-5 stars out of a 1-10 rating.

Comment: Oh I think I understand your riddle, max rank is 10, so 5.1 equals (ceiled to) 6 which is 2.5 stars... in this case you will have to use ceil($arr->rating);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop and compare the current loop iteration to `$arr->rating` to determine whether the star should be full, half, or empty.

```
// first convert the rating from score out of ten to score out of five
$rating = $arr->rating / 2;  

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $current = $rating - $i;
    if ($current >= 1) {
        $class = '';
    } elseif ($current > 0) {
        $class = 'half';
    } else {
        $class = 'empty';
    }
    echo "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-star $class\"></i>";
} ?>
```

Comment: I think $current = $arr->rating - $i; should be $current = $rating - $i;